# Uniqueness in ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, unique

I am using the first half code below to generate a unique ID.  Then i am using the entry generated in the first half as a variable for the second piece of code that generates another unique ID that is shorter, will the code i am using guarantee 100% uniqueness.  I am new so please bear with me:

PHP:

```
// 1st Piece of code

// Generate Guid 
function NewGuid() { 
    $s = strtoupper(uniqid(rand(),true)); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}
// End Generate Guid 

$Guid = NewGuid();

//2nd Piece of code

$alphabet = '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';    

function base_encode($num, $alphabet) {
    $base_count = strlen($alphabet);
    $encoded = '';

    while ($num >= $base_count) {

        $div = $num/$base_count;
        $mod = ($num-($base_count*intval($div)));
        $encoded = $alphabet[$mod] . $encoded;
        $num = intval($div);
    }

    if ($num) $encoded = $alphabet[$num] . $encoded;
        return $encoded;
}


function base_decode($num, $alphabet) {
    $decoded = 0;
    $multi = 1;

    while (strlen($num) > 0) {
        $digit = $num[strlen($num)-1];
        $decoded += $multi * strpos($alphabet, $digit);
        $multi = $multi * strlen($alphabet);
        $num = substr($num, 0, -1);
    }

    return $decoded;
}

ob_start();
echo base_encode($Guid, $alphabet); //should output: bUKpk
$ider = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: What's the matter with `uniqid()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the code i am using guarantee 100% uniqueness?

Of course it's not possible to 100% guarantee uniqueness with a random GUID. It's *very likely* that each GUID will be unique, but there is only a finite (but very large) number of GUIDs. If you generate enough of them you will eventually run out of unused GUIDs and be forced to generate a duplicate. And the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) means that randomly choosing GUIDs will on average give you a duplicate sooner than you might think.

But it's probably not worth worrying about in practice as even with the birthday paradox, it is still extremely unlikely to happen.

Comment: i am using that as a way to associate with users in the database and the content they generate.

Comment: What database engine are you using?  MySQL and Postgresql both support auto incrementing primary keys.  I would look into that.

Comment: @Mark how can i write a line of code that will check the database to see if whats generating is unique and if not it will run again and until it has generated a unique id..

Comment: @sberry2A I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: @AAA: Add a unique constraint to the column in your database.

Comment: What @Mark write in his answer is completely correct.  However, this is not something you should need to do in PHP.  MySQL (which phpmyadmin is actually using) has the ability to add auto incrementing primary keys.  Google "mysql auto increment primary key" to see what it is, and how it would be useful in your case.

Comment: @AAA.  That is good that it is a primary key, but look at "auto increment" to allow the primary key to be incremented by the database itself.  So, for instance, your first 5 records inserted could be id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  When you insert a new record it gets assigned id 6 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this class: http://www.shapeshifter.se/2008/09/29/uuid-generator-for-php/